# How do I show the date in the clock indicator?

Tags: unity, indicator

There is no GUI way to show the date or the day (or adjust the time format) in Unity's indicator-datetime application in Natty.

Answer (score 23):

I blogged about this today [here](http://penguindroppings.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/show-the-date-in-nattys-unity/).

Basically, this can be adjusted via dconf-editor (under /apps/indicators/datetime) from
 the  [dconf-tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dconf-tools) package, or by using `gsettings` in a terminal:

For 11.04:

Click on the Clock and choose "Time and Date Settings":

[image]

For 11.04 on the command line:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-date true
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-day true
```

For 10.10 (command line only unfortunately):

```
gsettings set org.ayatana.indicator.datetime show-date true
gsettings set org.ayatana.indicator.datetime show-day true
```

Comment: Strange. When I click on "Time and Date Settings" nothing happens. The command line bits worked though.